# Is possible to download image by URL and get its local path in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, download

I searched for way to download images by URLs and get there local path.

For example :

If my URL is: **https://static.pexels.com/photos/207171/pexels-photo-207171.jpeg**

I want to download this image and get its path such as this: **file///...../*.jpeg**

Comment: Short answer: no you can't do it in browser

Comment: You can **detect** when an image is downloaded client-side - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download, but you would need either NodeJS or another server-side language to actually initiate the download (and check the download location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatley (or luckily) you cannot access the file system from client-side JavaScript as the browser executes it. This is for security reasons.

The only way to access a file from the browser is the HTML file-input `<input type="file" />`.

To access the file system with JavaScript, you would need to use NodeJS and its fs-API.